# Incrementing word count from a stringstream

Tags: c++

I'm still learning C++ and i came up to an expression that's proving hard to understand.

Basically it takes cin input to a istringstream, which is then processed to keep individual words and it's counts (number of times it appears) in a map container 'words'

The code

```
std::map<string, int> words;

std::istream_iterator<string> begin(cin); 
std::istream_iterator<string> end;

while(begin != end ) 
   words[*begin++]++;
```

If someone could explain the code of the while loop for me? I know the end result, just want to know how exactly it does it. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't know what an `istream_iterator` is (and does for you), or the how default insertion happens for a `std::map<>`'s `operator []`, explaining that single expression may take awhile. See [this for `istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), and [this for `std::map::operator []`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). In case it wasn't obvious, there is a *tremendous* amount of functionality going on in that little line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regarding `std::istream_iterator<T>`:** this type provides an iterator interface to stream I/O.  Here, `begin` and `end` are iterators (you can think of them being iterators in a "virtual" container of `string`s, represented in the input in `cin`).

Because `begin` is initialised with `cin`, it will become what I'll call an "active" iterator: it will read from `cin` the first time it is dereferenced (like `*begin`), and the first time it is deferenced after each pre- or post-increment (`begin++`).

Because `end` is not initialised with anything, it becomes a special "end marker" iterator, rather than an active iterator.  The sole purpose of this special iterator value is to be something that an active iterator can compare equal to once it reaches the end of the file.

In this way, reading a series of `T` (in this case, `string`) from a file can be shoehorned into an ordinary iterator traversal of a container :)

**[EDIT: Clarified behaviour of `operator[]()`.]**

**Regarding `std::map<string, int>`:** you can think of a map as a very general type of array that can be indexed by things besides small integers -- in this case, strings.  The `std::map<K, T>` type overloads `operator[]()` to return a reference to the existing element identified by the key argument, with the additional (often helpful, as it is here) feature that if no element with that key exists in the map, it will be added with a default value (0 for `int`) and a reference to this brand-new element will be returned.

Comment: Thanks, but i didn't mean the condition of the loop, when i said inside, my bad! Thanks anyways! I understand the conditon and iterators, just the code below that is confusing

Comment: @user2896358: Ah :)  Well I've added some stuff about how maps work.  Interestingly I thought that was the more obvious part :-P

Comment: +1 @user2896358 regarding the last sentence in this answer, when a key is accessed via `operator[]` and there is no matching entry. a new one is created and the value type of the map (the second template parameter) is added by value-initialization via `Type()` (note the parens). In this case, that means `int()`. By the C++ standard, an integral value-initialization becomes zero-iniitailization, which means the initial integer is 0; exactly what you want when first hitting a new entry. C++11 8.5, sec 10,7,5 cover this in detail.

Comment: Ahh yes! The subscript operator! So it returns a reference if the key exists, otherwise it adds it with the default value. Am i going somewhere? Thanks! :D

Comment: @user2896358 yes, you understand how it works; either way you get back a reference to the value entry in the map. Either it was added, or it was already there. And technically you can (and should) do this: `++words[*begin++];` (and look at the content length of this answer, and what I said in general comment above. there is a LOT going on in that little statement, and explaining it isn't entirely trivial).

Comment: Where would words[*begin++]++ be a problem instead of ++words[*begin++]? Yep, I know its trivial, but sometimes little things go a long way, and knowing just gives me the peace :))

Comment: @user2896358: The only difference here is that it's possibly faster to use the preincrement form because then the compiler does not have to generate a temporary copy of the original value to become the overall expression's value.  In all likelihood that will be optimised away here, but you can never be too sure.

Answer (score 3):

1. *begin - taking iterator value
2. *begin++ - then incrementing iterator
3. words[*begin++] - passing value from step 1 to map [] operator, which means to get a value by key.
4. words[*begin++]++ - incrementing that value.

For all strings from cin we search an int in the map and increment it. Seems like we counting equal strings.

Answer (score 3):

Just break it down into multiple lines and save the intermediate results if you have trouble understanding the compressed one-liner.

```
std::map<std::string, int> words;

std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(std::cin); 
//default constructor creates an end of stream iterator
std::istream_iterator<std::string> end_of_stream; 

while(begin != end_of_stream ){
    std::string from_cin = *begin;     //reads from std::cin 
    int &count_ref = words[from_cin];  //can create a new entry 
    count_ref++;                       //increment value in the map
    begin++;                           //advance the stream_iterator
}
```

relevant pages for reference of the exact semantics are the

[isstream_iterator constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator/)

[isstream_iterator operator *](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/operator%2a/)

[map operator []](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5b%5d/)

Comment: This is actually a fairly accurate breakdown.

Answer (score 2):

The subscript operator in std::map behaves the following way. If there is no element that corresponds to the key then it is created and zero initialized. Otherewise it returns reference to the value type.

So in your code  expression

```
words[*begin++]
```

returns either existent value of type value_type that is int that corresponds to the string object equal to *begin or 0 because a new object was created with key *begin. After that the returned value is incremented.

```
words[*begin++]++;
```

Maybe it would be better to cite simply the C++ Standard

> T& operator[](const key_type& x);  1 Effects: If there is no key
>   equivalent to x in the map, inserts value_type(x, T()) into the map. 
>   2 Requires: key_type shall be CopyConstructible and mapped_type shall
>   be DefaultConstructible.  3 Returns: A reference to the mapped_type
>   corresponding to x in *this.  4 Complexity: logarithmic.